# How do I fix my code?

Tags: java, validation, date, input, user-input

Hello I am working on a project and I am trying to figure out what is wrong with my code so that it will print correctly. Write a Java program that prompt the user for the day and month (both integers) of his or her birthday, and then prints the appropriate astrological sign.

```
public class Birthday {
    public static void main(String args [] ) {
        String birthday = System.console().readline("Enter your birthday, month then day.");
        float value = Float.parseFloat(birthday);
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) {
            System.out.println("Invalid month please try again.");
        }

        else if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
            System.out.println("Invalid day please try again.");
        }

        else if (month = 1 || month = 12) {

        }

        else if (day >= 22 || day <= 19); {
            System.out.println(birthday + "Capricorn");
        }
    }
}
```

These are the errors that I get:

```
Birthday.java:3: readline(boolean) in java.io.Console cannot be applied to (java.lang.String)
    float birthday = System.console().readline("Enter your birthday, month then day.");
                                     ^
Horoscopes.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable month
location: class Birthday
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) {  
            ^
Horoscopes.java:4: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable month
location: class Birthday
        if (month < 1 || month > 12) {  
                         ^
Horoscopes.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable day
location: class Birthday
    else if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
             ^
Horoscopes.java:8: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable day
location: class Birthday
    else if (day < 1 || day > 31) {
                        ^
Horoscopes.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable month
location: class Birthday
    else if (month = 1 || month = 12) {
             ^
Horoscopes.java:12: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable month
location: class Birthday
    else if (month = 1 || month = 12) {
                          ^
Horoscopes.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable day
location: class Birthday
    else if (day >= 22 || day <= 19); {
             ^
Horoscopes.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable day
location: class Birthday
    else if (day >= 22 || day <= 19); {
                          ^
9 errors
```

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: I cannot see where you are setting `month` or `day`

Comment: I continue to keep getting errors. I get can't find symbol.

Comment: Hi. Indent your code properly. Describe specifically the problem you're having. Use a sensible title for your question that indicates your problem.

Comment: @Neil how would I fix that then?

Comment: Please, add the error messages you get and the tracebacks. Also please change the title to something that describes the problem in question.

Comment: @MikhailKaravashkin I added the error messages that I get

Answer (score 2):

From first glance, you did not define what `month` are `day`.

Also, what you are doing is `Float.parseFloat(birthday)` but all this will do is give you a `float` that looks something like this:

If I input `20150713` I will get

`float value = 20150713.00`

This doesn't separate them into months and days.

What I would recommend is, instead of turning the `String birthday` into a float, I would convert it in to a date structure.

Once you have a date structure, let's say something like `Date` or `LocalDate`, you can then compare the `month` and `day`.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to do something like this (only partially, I don't want to spoil your homework):

```
public static final void main(String args...) {
    while(true) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("please enter the month in which you are born:");
        int month = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("please enter the day in which you are born:");
        int day = sc.nextInt();
        if (!checkMonth(month)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid month please try again.");
            continue;
        } else if (!checkDay(day)) {
            System.out.println("Invalid day please try again.");
            continue;
        } else {
            // todo: work with valid birthday
        }
    }
}

public static boolean checkMonth(int month){
   // todo: check if valid
   return true;
}

public static boolean checkDay(int day){
   // todo: check if valid
   return true;
}
```

Comment: I added some of what you suggested to my project and I'm getting an error saying reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
1 error

Comment: i was just giving you an idea of how to tackle the task of reading user input in a while loop, until it doesn't contain any errors. you do actually have to implement the methods `boolean checkDay(String s)` and `boolean checkMonth(String s)`. Also `String readBirthday()` has to be implemented by you..

Comment: here you go, i added a bit more detail. also: you actually want to pass both parameters (month and day) to the checkDay(...) method, since you'll need the month to check if the day is valid (you actually also need the year because of leep-years..)